# Which method have to be called?

Tags: java

[Solution Question 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXBgz.png)Kann mir jemand erklären wieso bei den Aufrufen 1 und 5 der Datentyp von C zu B geändert wird bzw. wieso die Methode print(B b) aus Klasse Print2 aufgerufen wird? 
Danke!

Can somebody explain me why the type of C is be casted to B in 1 and 5? Why is method print(B b) of class Print2 being runned?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you intend to include some code with this question?

Comment: bitte lese dir die Regel von Stackoverflow. Deine Frage ist sehr schlecht. sie erklärt gar nicht was di brauchst. Und es ist ein Englisches Forum

Comment: Please include the information from the link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is a subclass of `A`, `C` is a subclass of `B`.

In the call 1 `c` can be casted to `B` because its class `C` is a subclass of `B`.

In the call 5 `c` is not casted to anything since `P2` has a method `print(C c)`.